# Adding Assembly to ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, web-config, assemblies

I want to use the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) in my ASP.Net project so that I can access the windows task scheduler from within my website. From what I have learned so far I need to add a reference to the assembly dll to my web.config. is that right? How do I figure out the public key token for the assembly file though? Is there any other way than using the 'sn.exe' utility, because I don't have the .net SDK installed and I unfortunately have no option of doing so on this computer. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to do anything with `sn.exe` or the public key token.

If you are working in a Web *Site*, right click your web-site in the Solution Explorer and click "Add Reference". It will create a Bin folder for you if there isn't one, then add the assembly to the bin.

If you are working in a Web *Application*, use the Add Reference dialog by right clicking "References" in the solution explorer.

**EDIT**:

> thank you but i am not using visual studio at all. all i have is IIS and I use notepad for editing. the server side portion of my website is written in jscript.net

You will probably be adding a Reference with the web.config then, such as:

```
<system.web>
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="YourAssemblyNameInBin" />
    </assemblies>
</system.web>
```

Place your assembly in the Bin, and change `YourAssemblyNameInBin` to the name of the assembly on disk without the extension.

You don't *have* to include the version, culture, and public key token of the assembly. If you want to though, you *can* use the `sn.exe` tool to display the public key token like so:

```
sn.exe -T "PathToAssembly"
```

Note that the T is capital. If the assembly is not signed - then you must omit the public key token from the reference.

Comment: hello vcsjones, thank you but i am not usin visual studio at all. all i have is IIS and I use notepad for editing. the server side portion of my website is written in jscript.net